# Access denied when I try to delete the user menu

Tags: users

How can I delete a user menu in Drupal 7? It throws me an access denied error, though I am logged in as user #1. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete any of the following menus; they come with the core. You can delete any menu you created yourself.

[image: Drupal 7 core menus]

To disable them from displaying go to admin/structure/block.

Comment: From the description given by the OP this is not the problem, as for those menu there isn't a delete link. If the OP would write the URL directly on the browser's URL field, then he should get an "page not found" error, not the "access denied" error.

Comment: There's no blocks in regions that displays @user_menu@

Comment: Disable it in your theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

maybe swithing for another source for secondary links at admin/structure/menu/settings is enough ?

OR

depending on theme you are using: go to theme's .info file and delete secondary links feature // change theme settings